# Can't modify workbook opened by macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel with a UserForm, this Userform has a CommandButton to open a workbook by:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= "XXXX.xlsx"
```

The workbook opens well, but i can't edit anything even i can't close the book.

I tried to use `ReadOnly := False` property but not works. I tried to change all security options in Excel to allow changes but it's the same.

But, if I close the Userform or stop the macro I can modify and close the opened book without problems.

I tried to put a `DoEvents` line after opening the book, thinking about the macro runs code and locks the book, but the problem is still there.

Any idea?

pd: Office 2016 home & Bussines Activated.

Comment: If your userform is opened modally (the default) then that is quite normal. You cannot interact with Excel until the form is closed. If that's not what you want then change the form's `ShowModal` property to False.

Comment: That works perfect, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can show a userform modally or not by setting the [`ShowModal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251819.aspx) property of the userform or by using the `modal` option of the [`.Show`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251540.aspx) method.

```
UserForm.Show vbModal
```

or

```
UserForm.Show vbModeLess
```

The `.Show` method ignores the `ShowModal` property if the optional argument is given.